# C++ function decorator

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am looking for a way to decorate functions or lambdas in C++. The goal is to do something before and after the function call. As I've seen the closest thing to use is std::function but it needs to have the types of its arguments.

```
class FunctionDecorator
{
public:
    FunctionDecorator( std::function func )
        : m_func( func )

    void operator()()
    {
        // do some stuff prior to function call

        m_func();

        // do stuff after function call
    }

private:
    std::function m_func;
};
```

It would be great if by template type could be used in std::function and it could deduce it somehow when i pass pointer to a function or a result from std::bind. 
Is such thing possible in C++.

Comment: Just go full template, without std::function.

Comment: Well the thing is that i want to decorate a bound method. This means that i have to store the arguments that are passed to the function also, to use them later when i call the function.

Comment: Templates work with bound methods, you can pass in whatever can be ()ed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just go full template, without std::function:

```
template< typename Func >
class FunctionDecorator
{
public:
  FunctionDecorator( Func func )
    : m_func( std::move(func) )
  {}

  void operator()()
  {
    // do some stuff prior to function call
    m_func();
    // do stuff after function call
  }

private:
  Func m_func;
};

template< typename Func >
FunctionDecorator<Func> decorate(Func func) {
  return FunctionDecorator<Func>(std::move(func));
}
```

Comment: Yes and when the function has several arguments, std::bind will be used in client code to make a callable. Thanks.

Comment: This answer does not address situation when, decorated function have arguments.

Comment: I know, it's as it was requested. If you want arguments, you just need to also make operator() a template: `template< typename... Args > void operator()(Args &&... args) { m_func(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }`. You can then also handle the case where m_func returns something, making the thing arbitrarily complex.

Comment: Just for the record, I think Quentin's answer is better, and should be marked as such instead of mine. Yet, I think my solution should be used, unless Quentin's is needed, because it's more essential.

Comment: why `std::move` is used?

Comment: @user2449761 func is a generic object passed by value, and encapsulated in the decorator. It may contain some state, which may be less expensive to move, than it is to copy. By wrapping in `std::move` , I'm allowing the compiler to move, rather than copy, if `Func` allows it. Without `std::move` , the compiler would be forced to copy.

Comment: aren't you forcing a move constructor usage here (if move constructor is available)? Shouldn't you rather use `std::forward` and forwarding reference (perfect forwarding)?

Comment: @user2449761 If you want to forward, you can do so by declaring `decorate(Func&&)`, but you still have to decide if the `FunctionDecorator` is going to store a value or a reference. My decision was that `FunctionDecorator` stores the function by value, since I expect most `Func` to be light objects, and it keeps lifetimes easier. At that point, since the decorator will always store a value, it makes little sense to accept a reference in the function (yes, you're making an extra copy/move, in principle. C++ can get arbitrarly complex, I was trying to make something correct and minimal)

Comment: Also, since the user will be passing a `Func` that will be copied/moved inside of `FunctionDecorator`, the semantics of the `decorate` is clearer, if it takes func by value. Taking `Func&&` would make the function user think that (s)he has to guarantee the lifetime of func, unless (s)he read the implementation of `decorate`, which is something one should possibly not need.
If `FunctionDecorator` stored a `Func&&` rather than a `Func`, then I'd be fine with `decorate` also taking a `Func&&` and forwarding.

Answer (score 23):

Hmm. I may or may not have gone overkill.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct RetWrapper {
    template <class Tfunc, class... Targs>
    RetWrapper(Tfunc &&func, Targs &&... args)
    : val(std::forward<Tfunc>(func)(std::forward<Targs>(args)...)) {}
    
    T &&value() { return static_cast<T &&>(val); }
    
private:
    T val;
};

template <>
struct RetWrapper<void> {
    template <class Tfunc, class... Targs>
    RetWrapper(Tfunc &&func, Targs &&... args) {
        std::forward<Tfunc>(func)(std::forward<Targs>(args)...);
    }
    
    void value() {}
};

template <class Tfunc, class Tbefore, class Tafter>
auto decorate(Tfunc &&func, Tbefore &&before, Tafter &&after) {
    return [
    
        func = std::forward<Tfunc>(func),
        before = std::forward<Tbefore>(before),
        after = std::forward<Tafter>(after)
        
    ] (auto &&... args) -> decltype(auto) {
            
        before(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
        RetWrapper<std::result_of_t<Tfunc(decltype(args)...)>> ret(
            func, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...
        );
        after(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
        
        return ret.value();
    };
}

/*
 * Tests
 */

float test1(float a, float b) {
    std::cout << "Inside test1\n";
    return a * b;
}

void test2() {
    std::cout << "Inside test2\n";
}

int i = 0;

int &test3() {
    return i;
}

int main() {

    auto test1Deco = decorate(
        test1,
        [] (float a, float b) {
            std::cout << "Calling test1 with " << a << " and " << b << '\n';
        },
        [] (float a, float b) {
            std::cout << "Called test1 with " << a << " and " << b << '\n';
        }
    );
    
    float c = test1Deco(3.5f, 5.1f);
    
    std::cout << "Yields " << c << '\n';
    
    auto test2Deco = decorate(
        test2,
        [] () {
            std::cout << "Calling test2\n";
        },
        [] () {
            std::cout << "Called test2\n";
        }
    );
    
    test2Deco();
    
    auto test3Deco = decorate(
        test3,
        [] () {
            std::cout << "Calling test3\n";
        },
        [] () {
            std::cout << "Called test3\n";
        }
    );
    
    auto &i2 = test3Deco();
    i2 = 42;
    
    std::cout << "Global i = " << i << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
Calling test1 with 3.5 and 5.1
Inside test1
Called test1 with 3.5 and 5.1
Yields 17.85
Calling test2
Inside test2
Called test2
Calling test3
Called test3
Global i = 42
```

Comment: That's pretty nice, actually:) I marked the other answer because i need only the simple behavior i stated earlier and the other solution is simpler:)

Comment: The thing with your code is that it's C++14. I don't know if it's already formally standardized, but I'd not use it for production.

Comment: @GiulioFranco C++14 is officially live since last august. Clang already implements it, and GCC 5, which should be released soon.

Comment: @Quentin C++14 is not only finalized but also officially a standard (since January); it's supported in clang 3.5 and almost fully implemented in gcc 5.0. That being said - it should be possible to port this to C++11 (maybe with limitation to unary and binary functions).

Comment: @PatrykObara I'm not going to try :p

Comment: @GiulioFranco and now it does ! Also, my eyes hurt.

Comment: @Quentin I think "T&& value() { return std::move(val_); }" is no longer valid (I tried C++14 and C++20): "initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue"
 I love this example; still going strong after 7y :D

Comment: @Chris I think I get what was wrong -- `std::move` casts an `int &` return value to an `int &&`, which is incorrect. I replaced it with a `static_cast<T &&>` which does the right thing through reference collapsing (as `value`'s return type itself does). I'm kind of surprised it actually compiled before that ‍♂️

Comment: Can you add the standard required for this to work to your answer? The edit cache is full and doesn't allow me to do it and the original question includes the C++11 tag.

Answer (score 2):

[**Note:** edited a few hours after initial posting]

This perhaps isn't exactly what the OP was looking for, but it's still relevant and hopefully useful to others looking for answers.

Let's say you have a couple of functions that have slightly different signatures:

```
void foo1(int& x){ cout << "foo1(" << x << ")\n";}
void foo2(double& x){ cout << "foo2(" << x << ")\n";}
```

and you'd like to wrap a decorator around them both so as to standardise their signatures, e.g. turn them both into `void (*)(int)`.

Then you could do the following:

```
template<typename Q, void (*foo_p)(Q&)>
void wrapped(int x){
  Q v = 42.2 + x;
  foo_p(v);  
}

int main(){
   using foo_t = void (*)(int); // we coerce foo1 and foo2 into this type 

   foo_t k_int = wrapped<int, foo1>;
   foo_t k_double = wrapped<double, foo2>;

   k_int(-1); //cout: foo1(41)
   k_double(-1); //cout: foo2(41.2)   
   return 0;
}
```

Using the example `main` I've given here, clang inlines the whole thing, which is a good sign but not quite what we wanted to check.  If you make the example a bit more complex ([see live here](http://ideone.com/WUznbs)) you can see that it does indeed inline everything within each wrapper, i.e. `foo1` and `foo2` don't exist in standalone form, only in wrapped form.

Originally, I use a lambda in addition to the `wrapped<...>` template (making use of the fact that lambdas with no-capture can be converted to function pointers) but then I realized that the extra wrapping was redundant in this case.

This method should work for passing anything known at run time, which could even include a pointer to a mutable global (although that's getting pretty messy).

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include  <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    template <typename TResult, typename TParams>
    class CClassGenerique
    {
        typedef TResult (*uneFonction) (TParams);
    public :
        CClassGenerique (uneFonction f){ m_function = f; }
        void operator () (TParams t)    {  m_function (t); }
private :    
        uneFonction m_function;
    };

    template <typename TResult, typename TParams>
    TResult BasicFunction (TParams p)
    {
        TResult t=0;
        std::cout<<" Value = " << p <<endl;
        return t;
    }

    int main (int argc, char* argv[])
    {

        CClassGenerique<int, int>       c1 (BasicFunction<int, int>);
        CClassGenerique<int, char*>     c2 (BasicFunction<int, char*>);
        CClassGenerique<char*, char*>   c3 (BasicFunction<char*, char*>);


        c1(3);
        c2("bonsoir");
        c3("hello");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add a short description?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a decorator like in Python, you can try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename t>
auto make_function(std::string(*const x)(t))
{
    return [=](t number)->void { std::cout << x(number) << '\n'; };
}

auto funcint(int a) {
    return std::string("Number: ") + std::to_string(a);
}

auto funcstr(const char * a) {
    return std::string("Number: ") + a;
}

auto f1 = make_function(funcint);
auto f2 = make_function(funcstr);


int main()
{
    f1(5);
    f2("Hello");
}
```