# Generic function dispatch mechanism

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I am trying to write a generic function dispatch mechanism where I do some additional work before calling the actual function (e.g. time the function's execution). The following code works, except for functions of the type `void f(....)` since we are declaring ret.

```
#define execute(fn, ...)    exec_helper(#fn, fn, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define execute0(fn)        exec_helper(#fn, fn)

template <typename TASK, typename... ARGS>
auto exec_helper(const char *fn_name, TASK&& task, ARGS&&... args)
{
      //std::function<std::result_of_t<TASK(ARGS...)> ()> func
      //           = std::bind(std::forward<TASK>(task),
      //                       std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);

#ifdef TIME_FUNC
      auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
#endif

      auto ret = task(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);

#ifdef TIME_FUNC
      auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
      auto diff = end - start;
      auto time = std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(diff).count();
      std::cout << "\n" << fn_name << "\t = "
                << std::setprecision(3) << time << " ms\n";
#endif

      return ret;
}
```

Is there a way to make it work for these type of functions as well? Perhaps using some template tricks?

Comment: I *knew* I had already answered [something similar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28499168/3233393). Could be prettier now that I look back at it, but it's a starting point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the interesting feature of C++, is that you can write this:

```
return f();
```

even if the return type of `f` is `void`. In this way, you can actually avoid using `ret` variable.

Keeping this in mind, and how destructor works, you can wrap the work-before-task and work-after-task in a class — and call them in the constructor and destructor respectively, as shown below:

```
struct watch
{
     extern watch(char const *fn_name) 
            : _fn_name(fn_name),
              _start(std::chrono::steady_clock::now()) {}

    ~watch()
     {
       auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
       auto diff = end - _start;
       auto time = std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(diff).count();
       std::cout << "\n" << _fn_name << "\t = "
                << std::setprecision(3) << time << " ms\n";
     }

     char const *_fn_name;
     decltype(std::chrono::steady_clock::now()) _start;
};
```

and use it as:

```
template <typename TASK, typename... ARGS>
auto exec_helper(const char *fn_name, TASK&& task, ARGS&&... args)
{
 #ifdef TIME_FUNC
      watch start_watching { fn_name };
 #endif

     return task(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);
}
```

Hope that helps.

---

You can even generalize the wrapper class as:

```
struct invariant_executor //choose a more general name now!
{
   using F = std::function<void()>;

   invariant_executor(F before, F after): _after(std::move(after)) 
   {
       before(); 
   }

   ~invariant_executor()
   {
       _after(); 
   }
   F _after;
};
```

and use it as:

```
template <typename TASK, typename... ARGS>
auto exec_helper(const char *fn_name, TASK&& task, ARGS&&... args)
{
 #ifdef TIME_FUNC
      decltype(std::chrono::steady_clock::now()) start;
      invariant_executor local 
      {
         [&] {  start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); },

         [&] {
            auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            auto diff = end - start;
            auto time = std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(diff).count();
            std::cout << "\n" << fn_name << "\t = "
                << std::setprecision(3) << time << " ms\n";
         }
      };
 #endif

     return task(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);
}
```

Now you've the flexibility to execute any code in the constructor and the destructor of `invariant_executor`.

Comment: Your struct `watch` needs to capture `fn_name`.

Comment: @ex-bart: Yes. Thanks.

Comment: A very cool generic solution, I think this fits what I need well

Comment: @Omair Be aware that while well suited to and the neatest choice for many scenarios (such as this timing example), this approach isn't suitable if you want to be able to throw exceptions or have them propagate upwards from the code that executes after the wrapped function because it's executed in the destructor of the wrapper class. The approach in my reply is less elegant, but offers an exception safe alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`packaged_task`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task):

```
std::packaged_task<Sig> pack_task(std::forward<Task>(task));
auto fut = pack_task.get_future();

// pre-time stuff

// run task
pack_task(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

// post-time stuff

// get the result - works with either void or a real type
return fut.get();
```

That already takes care of the `void` special case, although now you'd have to come up with `Sig`, and deal with the overhead of constructing `pack_task`.

Comment: Isn't this... a bit overkill ?

Comment: *Just* bet me. Your answer doesn't wait for the result to become available before getting to the "post-time stuff" though, so a timer would give incorrect timings.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode You are not running the packaged_task on a different thread. The result is available as soon as `operator()` returns.

Comment: @T.C. Sorry, my misunderstanding of `packaged_task`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`std::packaged_task`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task) and wait for the [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future)s result to become available. This will have an overhead, of course.

```
template<typename Func, typename ... Args>
auto func(Func &&f, Args &&... args) -> decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...)){
    using return_type = decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...));

    std::packaged_task<return_type(Args&&...)> task(f);
    auto future = task.get_future();

    // do something

    task(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    // do something else

    return future.get();
}
```

Then your function can have any return type, even `void`.

Answer (score 0):

You can let `exec_helper()` dispatch to one of two helper functions `exec_helper2()`, depending on whether the return type is void or not.  These functions overload each other, but are distinguished by the type of their first parameter `isvoid`.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

#define TIME_FUNC

#define execute(fn, ...)    exec_helper(#fn, fn, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define execute0(fn)        exec_helper(#fn, fn)

template <typename TASK, typename... ARGS>
auto exec_helper2(std::false_type isbool,
                 const char *fn_name, TASK&& task, ARGS&&... args)
{
      //std::function<std::result_of_t<TASK(ARGS...)> ()> func
      //           = std::bind(std::forward<TASK>(task),
      //                       std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);

#ifdef TIME_FUNC
      auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
#endif

      auto ret = task(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);

#ifdef TIME_FUNC
      auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
      auto diff = end - start;
      auto time = std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(diff).count();
      std::cout << "\n" << fn_name << "\t = "
                << std::setprecision(3) << time << " ms\n";
#endif

      return ret;
}

template <typename TASK, typename... ARGS>
auto exec_helper2(std::true_type isbool,
                 const char *fn_name, TASK&& task, ARGS&&... args)
{
#ifdef TIME_FUNC
      auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
#endif

      task(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);

#ifdef TIME_FUNC
      auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
      auto diff = end - start;
      auto time = std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(diff).count();
      std::cout << "\n" << fn_name << "\t = "
                << std::setprecision(3) << time << " ms\n";
#endif
}

template <typename TASK, typename... ARGS>
auto exec_helper(const char *fn_name, TASK&& task, ARGS&&... args)
{
  return exec_helper2(std::is_same<std::result_of_t<TASK(ARGS...)>, void>{},
                      fn_name, std::forward<TASK>(task),
                      std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);
}

void void_f() {}
int int_f() { return 42; }

int main()
{
  execute0(void_f);
  execute0(int_f);
}
```

Comment: This was the type of template based solution I was expecting to use.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the following lines might work for you:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Func, typename T> class ResultStash {
 public:
  explicit ResultStash(Func f) : m_t(f()) {}
  T get() { return std::move(m_t); }
 private:
  T m_t;
};

template <typename Func> class ResultStash<Func, void> {
 public:
  explicit ResultStash(Func f) { f(); }
  void get() { return; }
};


template <typename Func>
auto wrap_function_execution(Func f) -> decltype(f()) {
  std::cout << "Doing something before executing the function" << std::endl;

  // Call f() and remember the result
  ResultStash<decltype(f), decltype(f())> result(f);

  std::cout << "Doing something after executing the function" << std::endl;

  // Return the result of f()
  return result.get();
}

void someVoidFunction(int * a) {
  if (a) {
    *a = 5;
    std::cout << "Setting a = " << *a << std::endl;
  }
}

int someNonVoidFunction(int a) {
  int b = 10;
  std::cout << "Multiplying " << a << " by " << b << std::endl;
  return a * b;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  int a;
  wrap_function_execution([&a] { someVoidFunction(&a); });
  auto b = wrap_function_execution([&a] { return someNonVoidFunction(a); });
  std::cout << "b = " << b << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This introduces a template class that holds the result of the underlying function in your wrapper, and is specialised for void functions. The use of std::move in the non-void version of the class should minimise overhead when 'releasing' the stashed result in your wrapper.

This has the following (slight) advantages over Nawaz's approach:

- It keeps the flow of your wrapper code in one place, rather than breaking it up over the constructor and destructor of the wrapping class.
- It avoids doing work in the destructor.
- It's easier to interact with the wrapped function result in the wrapper code that follows execution.

It has the following disadvantages:

- The result of the wrapped function must be moveable (though that's usually a good thing).
- It's more intrusive, i.e. harder to comment out.
- Nawaz's approach is more appealing from an RAII perspective.

The example code produces:

```
Doing something before executing the function
Setting a = 5
Doing something after executing the function
Doing something before executing the function
Multiplying 5 by 10
Doing something after executing the function
b = 50
```

Comment: *"It keeps the flow of your wrapper code in one place, rather than breaking it up over the constructor and destructor of the wrapping class."*. Please see my solution again, the general one, which surely doesn't do what you said.

Comment: @Nawaz You're right that your general one does have the wrapping 'before' and 'after' code in immediate succession in the source. But the point I was trying to make regarding the code flow (which I should have articulated better) still has a smidgen of validity in that for an execution order of ABC, your source reads ACB. I personally prefer your pre-generalised version. In my opinion, the generalised version is over-engineered. For one thing, it disguises the fact that the second wrapping block will be run in a destructor, leaving the unaware happy to throw exceptions therein.

Comment: Isn't this very similar to an std::packaged_task?

Comment: Yes, it's identical in intent. But this is cleaner and far lighter in weight. std::packaged_task is engineered with threading in mind (that's why it lives in <future>) and while it can legitimately be used serially as in alternative answers, I suspect you may end up compiling the use of a mutex, atomic or similar into your code unnecessarily through the use of std::future to execute and access the result of your packaged task.